# CSV File Reading, Filtering and Processing and displaying on console table form in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I have a CSV (Excel) file of a survey. I want to process and filter the data of different columns and display it into the console in a table with the different column name. What is the best way to do it using Node.js?

Survey File Column:
`Country | State | Age | Gender`

Expected after processing:
`Country | Female | Male | Total`

Conversion of the CSV file to JSON:

```
const csv=require('csvtojson');
const csvFilePath='survey.csv' 

csv().fromFile(csvFilePath)
    .on('json',jsonObj => { 
        console.log(jsonObj); 
    }) 
    .on('done', error => console.log('end'));
```

I have got up to here converting the csv file to json

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there any code you can share with us?

Comment: there are many csv parser node modules. and then you can use columnify to print data in tabular format.

Comment: `
const csv=require('csvtojson')

const csvFilePath='survey.csv'
csv()
.fromFile(csvFilePath)
.on('json',(jsonObj)=>{
    console.log(jsonObj);
})
.on('done',(error)=>{
    console.log('end')
})
`
I have got up to here converting the csv file to json @RamizWachtler

Answer (score 1):

```
var csv = require("fast-csv");
var path = require('path');
//Here file implies "example.csv"
csv.fromPath(file[0].path, {
headers:true
//objectMode: true
})
.on("json", function (data) {
Survey.push(data);
})
.on("end", function () {
console.log('data is added');
});
```